# Powershell function argument default: Weirdness when it has a type constraint

Tags: powershell

If I have a function parameter WITHOUT the type constraint:

```
> function a ($s=$null) {if ($s -eq $null) {Write-Host "HI"} if ($s -eq "") {Write-Host "KK"}}
> a
HI
```

Now if I add the type constraint to it, the $null is interpreted differently:

```
> function a ([string]$s=$null) {if ($s -eq $null) {Write-Host "HI"} if ($s -eq "") {Write-Host "KK"}}
> a
KK
```

I can't find doc that explain this. It's also not consistent.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The OP is looking for an explanation of the difference in the behavior of the two functions when the parameter is coerced into being a string in one version, but not in the other. I don't understand whats "not consistent" here, but the behavior demonstrated here *can* be explained.

Comment: I guess it's not consistent with C#, since I don't think casting or assigning `null` to a string will result in string.Empty in C#. But then there's no requirement that PowerShell be consistent with C# as they're different languages.  Similarly, F# also has different behaviors than C#, and it's by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example (function `a`), `$s` is equivalent to `$null` - it's truly null.

In your second example (function `b`), because you're casting `$s` to a `[string]` object, it's actually an empty `String` (equivalent to `[String]::Empty`), **not** `$null`.

You can check this by adding the following to each of your functions:

```
if($s -eq [String]::Empty){"empty!"};
```

Only `b` will print `empty!` - `a` will evaluate this to `$false`

Alternately, add this:

```
$s|get-member
```

`a` will actually throw an error - the same error you'll get if you run `$null|get-member`. `b` will show you that `$s` is a `string` and list all of the members of that class.